# Image is not shown in the Xamarin XAML Designers Preview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm in Xamarin Studio 6.1.1 on a Mac an try to design something with XAML in the Designer and wonder why labels are shown in the preview, but images are not.

If I run the project in the iOS-Simulator the image is shown.

This is my code:

```
<Image Source="images/bla_wifi.png" HorizontalOptions="LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand" Margin="70,70,70,0"/>
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center" XAlign="Center">
    <Label.Text>
Are you connected to the 
WiFi?
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Any idea what I can do to see the image in the preview?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem but with Visual Studio. So far the only suggestion I can give is to re-build the solution (it helps sometimes) and also mentally keep treating the Forms Viewer as experimental.